# Laravel app doesn't work after moving to Homestead

Tags: php, laravel, homestead

So I used XAMPP, but I had few problems with it, so my employer told me to move to homestead. I created VB and moved my laravel app folder to linked folder for homestead. I run all migrations and seeding and it successfully completed, but now I get this error: 
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwS5t.png)

What could be the problem? I haven't touched the code.

Comment: you are using PHP 7.2 on that box aren't you?  what version of Laravel?

Comment: The version of PHP you're using is probably `7.2 `which throws the error when you're trying to use `count` on a `null/false` etc. Downgrade PHP, or fix your code.

Comment: my composer.json file says that php: ">=5.6.4" and "laravel/framework": "5.4.*". Could you say how to config php version? I'm a bit new in these technologies

Comment: It's of my opinion that you should just downgrade to 7.1 like the answer says, but you should port your code to be better for 7.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Homestead.yaml` file you can add a `php: "7.1"` key to the site settings so specify which version of PHP you'd like to use for that site. This way you can easily swap PHP versions.